# C4700: uninitialized local variable when combining path

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++

When running this code :

```
TCHAR *getSettingsFilePath(TCHAR *defaultProfilePath)
{
    TCHAR *prefPath;
    PathCombine(prefPath, defaultProfilePath, "profile.xml");
    return prefPath;  // This returns valid path
}
```

The compiler throws a warning saying : **warning C4700: uninitialized local variable `prefPath` used**

The [PathCombine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function sets the `prefPath` to a desired path .

But when i try to initialize `prefPath` to `NULL` before running `PathCombine`, the compiler warning is gone but my function also returns `NULL` .

```
TCHAR *getSettingsFilePath(TCHAR *defaultProfilePath)
{
    TCHAR *prefPath = NULL;
    PathCombine(prefPath, defaultProfilePath, "profile.xml");
    return prefPath; // This will return NULL
}
```

What do i miss here ? What is the right way to initialize this pointer ?

Comment: [From the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571(v=vs.85).aspx): "You must set the size of this buffer to MAX_PATH to ensure that it is large enough to hold the returned string." and since you're returning it, it had better be dynamic or passed in by the caller (the latter usually preferred).

Comment: `TCHAR *prefPath = (TCHAR*)calloc(MAX_PATH, sizeof(TCHAR));`

Answer (score 1):

The `PathCombine` function writes into space which `prefPath` is pointing to.  Your first version only appears to work because, by chance, the random location that `prefPath` is pointing to happens to be space that you have access to, and nothing else was relying on that (that you noticed , anyway).

It does not allocate space. In fact it can't. The argument is passed by value, so the function cannot make any changes to the pointer `prefPath`. Be sure to mentally distinguish the two things: *the pointer*, and *the thing being pointed to*.

So you need to allocate some space. In C++ this would be a poor design for a function because it requires the caller to partake in memory management.  It's not clear from your tags whether you are coding in C or in C++ (those are different languages).

Assuming C for the moment, then you need to [pick a dynamic allocation function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366533(v=vs.85).aspx) , and also document that the calling code has to free the allocated memory when it has finished with it.

Possibly a better design would be to have the caller pass in a buffer of the right size (instead of returning a pointer to a dynamic allocation). This lets the caller choose whether they want automatic allocation or dynamic allocation; and which dynamic allocation function to use.